# SQL Server 2019 : Why is the generation of the explain plan is taking so much time (hanging)?

Tags: installation, parameters, freeze, sql-execution-plan, sql-server-2019

**Situation**

Same query and same volume on a new server (same hardware specs, processors, RAM, disk SSD, etc...) on SQL Server 2016 runs in 8 seconds and on SQL Server 2019 more than 3 hours.

**Step by step**

- Installed a new SQL Server 2019 database on a new server, to be the new production environment. Same number of processors, same memory, SSD disks, data in one disk, logs on other, etc ....
- Migrated the tables, views, stored procedures, the data, the indexes, rebuild all the indexes.
- Executed the ETL, reading from source production, and all is OK, execution times are within params.
- Configured the reporting tool (that generates SQL over the database), all ok.
- problem with some reports.
- Copy the SQL to the Management studio to debug and just to generate the explain plan of this query, on the SQL Server 2016 it takes 8 sec, but on the SQL Server 2019 several minutes (after 5 minutes, I cancelled the request)

Why?

Then I:

- checked the memory "Available physical memory is high"
- rebuilt the indexes
- confirm that the disks were SSD
- execute the explain plan and check if the CPUs where being used (monitor)
- updated the statistics (`exec sp_updatestats`)
- installed the CU9 and restart the SQL Server 2019 (not the server)
- cut the query to be able to generate the explain plan on both servers.
- compare explain plans (between 2016 and 2019) and change the "Cost Threshold for Parallelism" and the "Max Degree of Parallelism" to  0 because 2016 used parallelism and 2019 was not. Same problem.
- use HINT to force parallelism, but with same execution times again.
- then out of nothing and without HINT, it was using now parallelism on the short explain plan, but still unable to generate the complete explain plan.
- the query was reading from ## tables so I've created normal tables on the database, same problem.

**Bottom line**

For me, it's strange the amount of time that SQL Server 2019 needs to generate the explain plan, while the SQL Server 2016 only need a couple of seconds.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you set up 2019 to be running at version level 15? If so can you set to 13 (2016) and see if any different?

Comment: Hi Stu, I've changed to the Compatibility Level 110 (SQL Server 2012) and it's NOW working. The old server was 2012 and not 2016 as I posted, sorry for that. I've changed to 13 and then realized that the old server it's older ... it's 2012 ... Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe try experimenting with the legacy cardinality estimator option.

Comment: Some other queries did not performed very well so I've turned ON the Legacy Cardinality Estimator parameter as Stu proposed and changed back the compatibility level to SQL Server 2019 (150). End users have being testing in this past 2 weeks and it's all good. I've still some high write latency on the tempDB (>50) , but all it's working now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced very similar problem with SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU16-GDR) on windows 2019.
The query was a simple query like "select count(*) from Schema1.Table1 where report_date='2022-01-23' and type = 2 and DueDate='2022-03-18'". I just tried to see estimated execution plan but it took 3 minutes. When I went into details, I have realized that Statistic is created for DueDate automatically. Since the statistic is created, plan generation took just a few seconds. I  When I remove the statistics, again it took 3 minutes. When I created the statistics of DueDate manually, plan generation took a few seconds which was very good indeed.

To find solution I turned off AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS off and on, and then it behaved normal, plan generation took a few seconds. Here is the script.

ALTER DATABASE [DbName] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS OFF

GO

ALTER DATABASE [DbName] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON

GO

After this simple silly turning OFF and ON, even after removing the specific statistic of the column, the estimated plan was generated in seconds instead of minutes.